# Не работает некоторый функционал React компоненты при создании build версии приложения

Tags: javascript, reactjs, веб-программирование, react-hook

Есть вот такая компонента

```
const Game = () => {
    let fieldsArr = {}
    let fieldId = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            fieldsArr[fieldId] = {
                isClicked: false,
                pos: [j, i],
                user: '',
                isHover: false
            }
            fieldId++
        }
    }

    let [user, setUser] = useState('cross')

    let [win, setWin] = useState('')

    let [fields, setFields] = useState({...fieldsArr})

    let [score, setScore] = useState({
        cross: 0,
        circle: 0
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        let checkWinOrDraw = analyzeMap(fields)
        if (checkWinOrDraw) {
            if (checkWinOrDraw !== 'draw') {
                console.log(score)
                setScore(prevScore => ({...prevScore, [checkWinOrDraw]: prevScore[checkWinOrDraw]++}))
                console.log(score)
            }
            setWin(checkWinOrDraw)
        }
    }, [fields])

    const onClick = (e) => {
        const fieldId = e.target.id
        if (!fields[fieldId].isClicked) {
            setFields(prevFields => ({
                ...prevFields,
                [fieldId]: {
                    ...prevFields[fieldId],
                    isClicked: true,
                    user: user
                }
            }))
            setUser(prevUser => prevUser === "cross" ? "circle" : "cross")
        }
    }

    const handleModalClose = () => {
        setFields({...fieldsArr})
        setWin('')
    }

    const handleMouseEnter = (e) => {
        let fieldId = e.target.id
        if (!fields[fieldId].isClicked) {
            setFields(prevFields => ({
                ...prevFields,
                [fieldId]: {
                    ...prevFields[fieldId],
                    isHover: true
                }
            }))
        }
    }
    const handleMouseLeave = (e) => {
        let fieldId = e.target.id
        if (!fields[fieldId].isClicked) {
            setFields(prevFields => ({
                ...prevFields,
                [fieldId]: {
                    ...prevFields[fieldId],
                    isHover: false
                }
            }))
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <ScoreBoard score={score}/>
            <div className="shadow tic-tac-toe">
                {
                    Object.keys(fields).map(key => {
                        return (
                            <div
                                key={key}
                                id={key}
                                className={
                                    `shadow tic-tac-toe__field bg-gradient ${fields[key].user ? fields[key].user === 'cross' ? 'bg-primary' : 'bg-danger' : 'no'}`
                                }
                                data-column={fields[key].pos[0]}
                                data-row={fields[key].pos[1]}
                                data-user={fields[key].user}
                                onClick={onClick}
                                onMouseEnter={(e) => handleMouseEnter(e)}
                                onMouseLeave={(e) => handleMouseLeave(e)}
                            >
                            <span id={key}
                                  className={`shape ${fields[key].user} ${!fields[key].user && fields[key].isHover ? user : ''}`}
                                  data-user={fields[key].user}
                            />
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
                <div className={`message${win ? " open" : ""}`} id="win">
                    <div className="shadow message__body">
                        <h1 className={`message__title text-${win === 'cross' ? 'primary' : win === 'circle' ? 'danger' : 'default'}`}>
                            {win === 'cross' ? "Победили крестики!!!" : win === 'circle' ? "Победили нолики" : "Ничья."}
                        </h1>
                        <button onClick={handleModalClose}
                                className={`message__button btn btn-${win === 'cross' ? 'primary' : win === 'circle' ? 'danger' : 'dark'}`}>Start
                            new game!
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

const ScoreBoard = ({score}) => {
    return(
        <div className="shadow scoreboard">
            <h1 className="scoreboard__title">Счёт</h1>
            <div className="user-panel">
                <div className="shadow user-info bg-primary bg-gradient">
                    <span className="x-user-score">{score.cross}</span>
                </div>
                <div className="shadow user-info bg-danger bg-gradient">
                    <span className="o-user-score">{score.circle}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

на локалке всё работает и счёт прибавляется, и багов не возникает, но в build версии и при деплое на gh счёт перестаёт работать, то есть в useEffect setScore не увеличивает счёт на единицу почему-то, почему это происходит? https://sinelnikov-web.github.io/react-tic-tac-toe/

Answer (score 0):

UPD: Вопрос решён, проблема была в `setScore(prevScore => ({...prevScore, [checkWinOrDraw]: prevScore[checkWinOrDraw]++}))`, а именно в `prevScore[checkWinOrDraw]++`, который я заменил на `prevScore[checkWinOrDraw] + 1` и всё заработало, могу предположить что такое поведение было из-за того, что была постфиксная запись инкремента, других вариантов придумать не могу. Но всё же не понятно, почему в локальном виде всё работало, но в build версии нет